# Read a locally stored image as the background image for subtraction

Tags: .net-core, emgucv

I'm using `Emgu.CV` and planning to use background subtraction. I want to do something fairly simple and read two background images from my local disk, and use one of them as the background image and the other one as the overlay to compare with / the mask.

I haven't got far though, because the signature of the method is very different than just accepting a file. I'm guessing I'm missing some conversion from a `File.Read` to `IInputArray`

```
IBackgroundSubtractor backgroundSubtractor = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

IInputArray inputImage; // how do I create an instance of an InputArray from a local file?
IOutputArray mask;

backgroundSubtractor.Apply(imputImage, mask);
```

How do I go from a file in `C:\<somepath>\someimage1.png` to formats `IInputArray, IOutputArray` below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmguCv offers different methods to load images from file (see V1 and V2 below). For the mask you just need to define a new Mat object and it will be allocated and filled automatically when you call `backgroundSubtractor.Apply(input1, mask);`

```cs
    //V1 load image
    var input1 = new Mat(@"C:\<somepath>\someimage1.png");
    
    //V2 load image
    Mat input2 = CvInvoke.Imread(@"C:\<somepath>\someimage1.png", ImreadModes.AnyColor);
    
    var mask = new Mat();
    IBackgroundSubtractor backgroundSubtractor = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    backgroundSubtractor.Apply(input1, mask);
```

The Mat class implements IInputtArray as well as IOutputArray.

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: While this worked in terms of reading the image, I can't seem to subtract one image from another in a decent way (literally the same image, I've just added something on one of them - which I'm expecting the subtraction to catch). Would you be able to point me to the right direction?

Comment: If you just wanna subtract images use the [CvInvoke.Subtract](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.3.0/document/html/74ffe364-511b-a414-ad25-c85f7345e643.htm) method. In general, have a look at the docs for [CvInvoke](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.3.0/document/html/bb544594-4bf7-5a11-594c-f143b226f1da.htm) it give a quite large overview of the emgucv capabilities